# JQuery Datatable Feature enable / disable Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

The Jquery data table allows features such as pagination, search, page information, and # of items in one page. I only want the pagination functionality, and want to disable the rest. Could someone take a look at my code and see where the problem is?

```
$('#myTableId').DataTable()({
   "search" : false
   "info": false
});
```

Comment: I think you're missing a comma in the parameters of DataTable.  Try this $('#myTableId').DataTable()({ "search" : false, "info": false });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra parenthesis from Datatable function, you must call it with the options inside

```
$('#myTableId').DataTable({ "search" : false, "info": false });
```

Comment: Thank you Tushar! It works. One more question. I original have anohter line of code to disable one of the columns. But I was not able to combine them together.                   
              $('#myTableId').DataTable().column(0).visible( false );
          $('#myTableId').DataTable({
      
      "info": false 
      
      
           });

Comment: I am not getting it. Can you explain bit more, or post another question :) If this helped then please accept or upvote.

Comment: Thanks for the help Tushar. I just figured it out by incorporating the other line of code into the datatable section. Thanks!